# e-mail validation in php not working, tried filter_var and preg_match

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to validate whether a use entered a password and an e-mail address, whether the e-mail address is valid and whether the pwd is correct.

The code works well for checking whether a password and an e-mail address have been entered and also whether the password is correct. But the e-mail validation falls through. It doesn't matter what I enter in the form, I am being redirected and the failure message never shows.

Why?

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
     <?php
      $check_email = $_POST['who'];
      $regex = '/^[_a-z0-9-]+(\.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]+)*(\.[a-z]{2,4})$/';
      if (preg_match($regex, $check_email)) {
        header("Location: xyz.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']));
        return;
      } else {
          $failure = "E-mail must have an @-sign";**




<h1>Please Log In</h1>
<?php



**if ( $failure !== false ) {

echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($failure)."</p>\n");
}**

?>
<form method="POST">
<label for="nam">E-Mail</label>
<input type="text" name="who" id="nam"><br/>
<label for="id_1723">Password</label>
<input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Log In">
<input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
</form>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: works for me: https://ideone.com/IkSdyb

Comment: Why go through all that trouble if there is already a builtin function in PHP for you: `filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`?

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, didn't work either...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a VERY large amount of key syntax. 
First of all, you have to verify whether the $_POST variable is set. 
Second, you have to use filter_var if you want the most simplistic approach. 
Third, you are missing A LOT of end-of-file brackets.
 Fourth, asterisks are redundant in PHP. 


**SIDE NOTE : REMEMBER TO SANITIZE USER INPUT USING mysqli_real_escape_string**


Here is your new code.

```
   <?php
 if(isset($_POST['who']))
 {
    $check_email = $_POST['who'];
    if (filter_var($check_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) 
    {
        header("Location: xyz.php?name=".urlencode($_POST['who']));
        return;
    } 
    else 
    {
        $failure = "E-mail must have an @-sign";
    }
    ?>
    <h1>Please Log In</h1>
    <?php
    if (!empty($failure)) 
    {
        echo('<p style="color: red;">'.htmlentities($failure)."</p>\n");
    }
 }
 ?>
 <form method="POST">
    <label for="name">E-Mail</label>
    <input type="text" name="who" id="nam"><br/>
    <label for="id_1723">Password</label>
    <input type="text" name="pass" id="id_1723"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Log In">
    <input type="submit" name="cancel" value="Cancel">
 </form>

</div>
</body>
```

Comment: I recommend you look at w3schools, because many of the issues had to do with basic PHP syntax.

Comment: `return;` should be `exit;` after header

Comment: First - thanks for taking the time to write the comment in detail.
Second - I did not post the entire code because it seemed too long. I only posted the relevant bits since all of the other validations were working. So, the in the original code the $_POST variable is indeed verified.
Third - I tried filter_var as well and it did not work either.
Fourth - the asterics were just an attempt to highlight relevant part of the code.

Comment: I tried the above code but the e-mail is just not validated. It's as if the check wasn't there at all...

Comment: In the end the funtions filter_var or preg_match were not the issue at all. It was the squence of commands in php. But sometimes you keep staring at the wrong problem...

Comment: Still, I did my best for the information you provided... Please mark my answer as correct? I need the reputation...

Answer (score -1):

use the function : filter_var("example@gmail.com", FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)